# Edit Navigation Order in Sharepoint Designer?

Tags: navigation

If I wanted to sort some of the navigation items through the browser I go to Site Setting>Navigation>Navigation Editing and Sorting. This gets annoying, however, if I have more than a few items.

Is there a way to edit that stuff via Sharepoint Designer instead or some kind of addon or easier way? This particular subsite has over 350 pages that need to be sorted and grouped into headings and such and I'm not allowed to completely reorganize the setup itself so I'm stuck with Navigation and Editing. (don't you just love inherited sites?)

We're using Sharepoint 2010 and this is a publishing site.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately no, at least for SP2010. The designer itself will get you to the site setting page in browser.